# how to create a typescript project whit react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsx

I am new in react-native.
I would like to create a project in react-native with VS code.
I know how to init a project with command ``react-native init ProjectName```but when this create this a java .js not .tsx.
for example my project has app.js not app.tsx!
how to create this? how to change it?
thanks

Comment: The very first page in the official React Native environment setup guide specifies exactly how to do this. It's a good idea to at least *try* reading the documentation before asking questions.. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the template as typescript. init new project using below command

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

You can found the complete decumantation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript)

Comment: heads up for anyone who want to use this template: [it is deprecated](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/pull/320) since Jan 2023. Typescript is first class in RN 0.71, read [this](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/03/typescript-first)